# Calling javac the way Maven does

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Calling `mvn clean compile -X`

shows the following (few dependencies omitted to stay in question max char size):

```
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [/Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/src/main/java]
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerId = javac
[DEBUG]   (f) debug = true
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnWarning = false
[DEBUG]   (f) forceJavacCompilerUse = false
[DEBUG]   (f) fork = false
[DEBUG]   (f) generatedSourcesDirectory = /Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/target/generated-sources/annotations
[DEBUG]   (f) mojoExecution = org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile {execution: default-compile}
[DEBUG]   (f) optimize = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/target/classes
[DEBUG]   (f) parameters = false
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: it.u1.u2:stockapp:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT @ /Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) projectArtifact = it.u1.u2:stockapp:jar:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@633a2e99
[DEBUG]   (f) showDeprecation = false
[DEBUG]   (f) showWarnings = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipMultiThreadWarning = false
[DEBUG]   (f) source = 11
[DEBUG]   (f) staleMillis = 0
[DEBUG]   (s) target = 11
[DEBUG]   (f) useIncrementalCompilation = true
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using compiler 'javac'.
```

and also

```
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d /Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/target/classes -classpath /Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/target/classes:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.6.2/spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.6.2/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.9/logback-classic-1.2.9.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.9/logback-core-1.2.9.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.17.0/log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.0.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.17.0/log4j-api-2.17.0.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.32/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.29/snakeyaml-1.29.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-json-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.13.1/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.13.1/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.13.1/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.56/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.56/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.3.14/spring-web-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.14/spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.14/spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.3.14/spring-context-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.3.14/spring-expression-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-security-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.3.14/spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/5.6.1/spring-security-config-5.6.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/5.6.1/spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/5.6.1/spring-security-crypto-5.6.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/5.6.1/spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.7/aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/4.0.3/HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.3.14/spring-jdbc-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.6.0/spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.6.0/spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/5.3.14/spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.3.14/spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.32/slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.3.14/spring-aspects-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-validation-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.56/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.56.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.2.0.Final/hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.2/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/4.5.0/liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.13.1/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.13.1/jackson-annotations-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.13.1/jackson-core-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.13.1/jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.14/spring-core-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.3.14/spring-jcl-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.22/lombok-1.18.22.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-processor/1.3.1.Final/mapstruct-processor-1.3.1.Final.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct/1.3.1.Final/mapstruct-1.3.1.Final.jar: -sourcepath /Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/src/main/java:/Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/target/generated-sources/annotations: -s /Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/target/generated-sources/annotations -g -nowarn -target 11 -source 11 -encoding UTF-8
```

So I was under the impression that Maven makes this call using javac:

```
javac -d /Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/target/classes -classpath /Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/target/classes:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.6.2/spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.6.2/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.9/logback-classic-1.2.9.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.9/logback-core-1.2.9.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.17.0/log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.0.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.17.0/log4j-api-2.17.0.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.32/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.29/snakeyaml-1.29.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-json-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.13.1/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.13.1/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.13.1/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.56/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.56/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.3.14/spring-web-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.14/spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.14/spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.3.14/spring-context-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.3.14/spring-expression-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-security-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.3.14/spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/5.6.1/spring-security-config-5.6.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/5.6.1/spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/5.6.1/spring-security-crypto-5.6.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/5.6.1/spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.7/aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/4.0.3/HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.3.14/spring-jdbc-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/jakarta/transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/1.3.3/jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.6.3.Final/hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.2.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.2.Final.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.11.22/byte-buddy-1.11.22.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.2.3.Final/jandex-2.2.3.Final.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.2.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.5/jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/2.3.5/txw2-2.3.5.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.12/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.6.0/spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.6.0/spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/5.3.14/spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.3.14/spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.32/slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.3.14/spring-aspects-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.6.2/spring-boot-starter-validation-2.6.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.56/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.56.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.2.0.Final/hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.2/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/4.5.0/liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.13.1/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.13.1/jackson-annotations-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.13.1/jackson-core-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.13.1/jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.14/spring-core-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.3.14/spring-jcl-5.3.14.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.22/lombok-1.18.22.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-processor/1.3.1.Final/mapstruct-processor-1.3.1.Final.jar:/Users/u/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct/1.3.1.Final/mapstruct-1.3.1.Final.jar: -sourcepath /Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/src/main/java:/Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/target/generated-sources/annotations: -s /Users/u/Desktop/java_dev/projects/stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/target/generated-sources/annotations -g -nowarn -target 11 -source 11 -encoding UTF-8
```

But calling it on command line shows:

```
error: no source files
```

any help on what it's wrong ?

Comment: Please show the full project setup (directory structure) or even better make an example project on Github or alike...

Comment: I think this is testable/reproducible with any java project, this is using spring boot :)

Comment: It's not the question if you think it's testable/reproducible with any java project, because I have hundreds of projects which work fine ...so please show the setup etc. otherwise I can not even guess... nor help...

Comment: idk whether this works, but try deleting the `target` folder and recompile the project with maven again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your example:

```
stockapp-spring-boot (master)$ mvn clean compile 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] stockapp-spring-boot                                               [pom]
[INFO] stockapp                                                           [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------< it.raffaele.esposito:stockapp-spring-boot >--------------
[INFO] Building stockapp-spring-boot 1.2.2-SNAPSHOT                       [1/2]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ stockapp-spring-boot ---

 ...

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ stockapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 14 resources
[INFO] The encoding used to copy filtered properties files have not been set. This means that the same encoding will be used to copy filtered properties files as when copying other filtered resources. This might not be what you want! Run your build with --debug to see which files might be affected. Read more at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filtering-properties-files.html
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:copy-resources (Copy Vue frontend into Spring Boot target static folder) @ stockapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 8 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ stockapp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 27 source files to stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/target/classes
[INFO] stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/src/main/java/it/raffaele/esposito/app/service/MappingFunctions.java: stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/src/main/java/it/raffaele/esposito/app/service/MappingFunctions.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[INFO] stockapp-spring-boot/stockapp/src/main/java/it/raffaele/esposito/app/service/MappingFunctions.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for stockapp-spring-boot 1.2.2-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] stockapp-spring-boot ............................... SUCCESS [  0.090 s]
[INFO] stockapp ........................................... SUCCESS [ 21.988 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.339 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-17T20:12:05+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and no problems at all...

Comment: Yes, also works for me to build it with maven my question is about compiling the code using javac

Comment: Hm..there was written `But calling it on command line shows...` which implies something different. The https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html uses a component [plexus](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-compiler/plexus-compilers/) of which plexus-compiler-javac is used https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/tree/plexus-compiler-2.8.3/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-javac/ (you can configure maven-compiler-plugin to explicitly use [javac](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#forceJavacCompilerUse)

Comment: this `<forceJavacCompilerUse>` works, I understand now, thanks a lot !